# Memory-aware LRU caching in Python?

Tags: python, caching, memory-management, lru

I'm using Python 3's builtin `functools.lru_cache` decorator to memoize some expensive functions. I would like to memoize as many calls as possible without using too much memory, since caching too many values causes thrashing.

Is there a preferred technique or library for accomplishing this in Python?

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000404/automatic-cache-eviction-based-on-memory-consumption) lead me to a Go library for [system memory aware LRU caching](https://github.com/eaigner/last). Something similar for Python would be ideal.

---

**Note:** I can't just estimate the memory used per value and set `maxsize` accordingly, since several processes will be calling the decorated function in parallel; a solution would need to actually dynamically check how much memory is free.

Comment: If you can't find something out there that does this already, you can try leveraging psutil (http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) to roll your own.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking into right now—in fact, do you happen to know how to find the source for Python 3's `lru_cache` implementation? The easiest way would be to simply check the memory usage within the decorator. It would add some overhead for sure, but in this application I don't think it would be significant.

Comment: @Will for the source see [functools.py:370](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5d0783376c88/Lib/functools.py#l370) and a couple lines above for the cache key functions.

Comment: Or locally: Launch an interactive Python interpreter, `import functools` and just enter the module name `functools`. Works for any locating the source of nearly any Python module (except C extensions of course).

Comment: @Will BTW, `functools.lru_cache` was written by Raymond Hettinger. He posted several different (LRU) caching / memoization [recipes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/users/178123/tags/cache/), maybe you can find something useful or at least inspirational in those ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys, seems to be working well. Posted the code in my answer. Let me know if it can be improved at all!

Comment: I asked in https://github.com/tkem/cachetools/issues/152 We will see :)

Answer (score 22):

I ended up modifying the built-in `lru_cache` to use `psutil`.

The modified decorator takes an additional optional argument `use_memory_up_to`. If set, the cache will be considered full if there are fewer than `use_memory_up_to` bytes of memory available (according to `psutil.virtual_memory().available`). For example:

```
from .lru_cache import lru_cache

GB = 1024**3

@lru_cache(use_memory_up_to=(1 * GB))
def expensive_func(args):
    ...
```

**Note:** setting `use_memory_up_to` will cause `maxsize` to have no effect.

Here's the code: [`lru_cache.py`](https://gist.github.com/wmayner/0245b7d9c329e498d42b)