# python check memory usage and stop caching if memory usage is too high

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management

I hope to cache some DataFrames in memory to speed up my program (`calculate_df` is slow). My code is like

```
class Foo:
    cache = {}

    @classmethod
    def get_df(cls, bar):
        if bar not in cache:
            cls.cache[bar] = cls.calculate_df(bar)
        return cls.cache[bar]

    @classmethod
    def calculate_df(cls, bar):
        ......
        return df
```

Almost all of the time, the possible values of `bar` times the size of `df` fit into memory. However, I need to plan for cases that I have too many different `bars` and big `df` which make my `cache` cause memory issues. I hope to check memory usage first before I run `cache[bar] = calculate_df(bar)`.

What is the right/best way to do such memory checks?

Comment: What is the rule that tells you how much cache space you can use? What "memory issues" are occurring, and why are they a problem?

Comment: I haven't come across a "memory issue" yet but I'm just thinking about bad scenarios. Basically if memory usage is too high, I want to stop adding them to `cls.cache` and return directly.
I don't know what's the rule to tell me how much cache space I can use, I guess that's part of my question too. It seems like I can use `psutil.virtual_memory().available`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually operating on such memory level in Python, you might want to consider using the decorator [functools.lru_cache()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) where you can limit the number of items to `maxsize` that can be stored at any given point in time. Once `maxsize` is reached, it will evict the old items.

> **`@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128, typed=False)`**
>
> Decorator to wrap a function with a memoizing callable that saves up to the `maxsize` most recent calls

**Sample usage**

```
from functools import lru_cache

class MyClass:
    @lru_cache(maxsize=3)
    def duplicate(self, num):
        print("called for", num)
        return num * 2

obj = MyClass()
for num in [12, 7, 12, 12, 7, 5, 15, 5, 7, 12]:
    print(num, "=", obj.duplicate(num))
```

**Output**

```
called for 12
12 = 24
called for 7
7 = 14
12 = 24
12 = 24
7 = 14
called for 5
5 = 10
called for 15
15 = 30
5 = 10
7 = 14
called for 12
12 = 24
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My function is actually more complicated:
1. I want to clean up cache myself because I know in what circumstances they are no longer used. My cache cleanup strategy can reduces the size by hundreds of times
2. lru_cache seems to only consider maxsize of inputs only. In my case, that is only a very small factor. The more important factor is the size of the calculated DataFrame.
Therefore lru_cache doesn't seem a good solution to me. What do you think?

Comment: It seems like I can hack `lru_cache` to use `use_memory_up_to`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477284/memory-aware-lru-caching-in-python
but that'll be almost same as checking cache space myself